# WearableListenerService life cycle

Tags: wear-os

I am lost with the WearableListenerService life cycle. I was thinking that it would work like a normal service : when I destroy my mobile/wear app (in my case), I wanted to kill the service. But I noticed that the service is creating again when you destroy it, like if there was a "START_STICKY" behind.

I read the docs and it's written : `The life-cycle of this service is managed by Android Wear.`

What should I do then? Is there a way to kill properly this service or should I let the service alive and let android wear manage its life-cycle?

EDIT :

I forgot to mention the most important thing : the filter `<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />` is the one triggering the creation of the listener.

What I finally did is using a boolean value in that service to know when the application is opened (background/foreground) so I don't perform any action that would lead when the application is closed that could lead to an error (ui action).

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems like you want to receive certain callbacks only when your application is in front (since you said you wanted to "disable" that when the app is in background). If so, there is no need for you to use that service to begin with; you can register a live listener for any of the callbacks that you are interested in when your app starts and unregistered yourself when the app goes away. That said, the WearableListenerService is actually a short-lived service in the sense that it is started by framework when there is a relevant change or message and calls the appropriate callback that it provides and shortly after the callback is returned, the service is destroyed; this is the standard behavior for any service that is started through binding. Add a one-line log statements to the methods that the service provides and monitor your log to see which one of the callbacks are called when you see it started while you don't expect it to; that should give you a clue on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about the state of this service. It will destroy itself once it is finished working. You can add any cleanup code you need to run into the onDestroy() method, if that is relevant.

Comment: Yes, I added logs and noticed what you are telling. What bothers me is the following case : let's say we handle an offline/online mode (we display the UI depending if the mobile app is listening or not), I'd do something like sending a configuration message in the OnConnected method, and wait for a reply with a timer, and if no reply is given, then I can tell I am offline. But that would mean that everytime my service is created again, it would send a config message, even if I know I am already connected. How would I deal with that behaviour then?